# Como generar Código de Barras en pdf

Tags: python-3.x, django

alguien puede ayudarme, necesito generar el código de barras en pdf, **pero que no se guarde en el servidor, en lugar de eso se abra el pdf** y quede a criterio de quien lo genere si guarda o no. Actualmente genero los códigos en pdf y los guarda en el servidor.

```
def createBarCodes(request, ord_id):  
    PAGESIZE = A4
    canvas = Canvas("codigo.pdf", pagesize=PAGESIZE)
    orden = OrdenPaciente.objects.get(id=ord_id)
    examenes=ExamenesOrdenPaciente.objects.filter(orden_paciente_id=ord_id)
    y = 720
    for ex in examenes:
        sticker = label(str(ord_id)+str(ex.id), orden.paciente.nombres+' '+orden.paciente.apellidos+' Ord:'+ord_id+' Ex:'+str(ex.id))
        fill_sheet(canvas, sticker,ord_id, y)
        y-=55
canvas.save()
```

Comment: Si vas a serializar en un PDF, tienes que generar el archivo, así sea en una ubicación temporal, y luego ofrecerlo para descarga.

Comment: Probablemente puedas hacer uso de `io.StringIO()` para crear un "falso archivo" en memoria. Depende de la API que te ofrezca la biblioteca que usas para generar el PDF y de cómo lo retornes después desde Django.